# Get a file's creation time with GLib

Tags: file, glib

it can't be that hard but I just don't get it: I want to retrieve a file's creation time (not modification time) from within GLib (I am using Vala at the moment, but C or any other language with GLib Binding would do). I have this code:

```
File file = File.new_for_commandline_arg(args[1]);
FileInfo info = file.query_info("*", 0);
uint64 t = info.get_attribute_uint64(FileAttribute.TIME_CREATED);
stdout.printf("%llu\n", t);
```

which prints out 0 (indicating "invalid" according to the docs) on any file. I know there is a  `info.get_modification_date()` available, which works as expected, but I need the time of the file's creation.

Google did not give me any results, so I hope someone here could give me a clue in the right direction.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your code on Linux, it's simply because that information is [not available](http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/). You can check with `g_file_info_has_attribute` if a given attribute is actually available for a `GFileInfo`.